# How should we retrieve an individual post now that /[post-id] is deprecated in v2.4?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just tried through the Graph API Explorer with this path /v2.4/10153513872748291 and I've got this result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular links API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

But https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ doesn't say anything about deprecation.

I'm not sure if I miss something, or there's another way to get info about an individual post.

Edit: v2.3 works, but v2.4 is the latest one.

Comment: Use a different 'v'?

Comment: Yes, v2.3 works, but I want to use the right version, which is v2.4.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Looks like you now need to the combination of the id of the user or page that made the post (or whose wall it is on), an underscore, and then the post id.

For your example post, `10153513872748291`, that is made by a page `Drama-addict`, that has the id `141108613290` – so `141108613290_10153513872748291` will work.

And so does `788239567865981_10153513872748291`, because `788239567865981` is the id of the user making the post.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That works. One question: how (or where?) do you find out that it needs to be userId_postId?

Comment: When you request user or page posts via `/{user_or_page_id}/feed`, prior API versions return that format as value of the `id` field already … so I just tried if that worked with v2.4 ;-)

Comment: Now I'm just getting an error `{\"message\":\"(#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":12,`

Comment: @bzupnick that might be a case of changed API behavior – did you get a default picture (question mark) before for some/all posts? If so, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes – “Picture Error”

Comment: @CBroe By any chance do you know how to create the userID_postID format and use them in GraphRequest in Android? I already have the user id and the post id, but I don't know how to use them in GraphRequest in Android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: new GraphRequest(mMainActivity.mAccessToken, "141108613290_10153513872748291", params, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback()

I used your example ids and it worked on Android, but when I use other ids from posts shared public by others, it returns "unsupported get request ....." Take this link for example, I extracted the ids from it and used in Graph API Explorer but it returns the same error, why?

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=10153244578850686&substory_index=94&id=700580685

Comment: This is apparently no longer working  `"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'XXX_XXX' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"`

Comment: @PhoenixNoor it works perfectly fine. Facebook themselves return this kind of ids via the API nowadays. Most likely your app does not have the necessary permission to read that particular object.

Comment: For picture use /attachment node in the following format: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/[page_id]_[post_id]/attachments?access_token=xxx

Comment: @CBroe: I want to get the video details from the post in this type of url https://www.facebook.com/shreyaghoshal/posts/10155774118036484  . I get this link from the Facebook app in iOS device. Except this copied link and Facebook login user details i don't have any details about this url .  Facebook version is above the 2.4 version. I used the code graph request to get the details like "/{postid}" it shows the (#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher. Please give suggestions and code to solve this issue.

Comment: @Ajay as I explained, you need to replace the user name with the numeric id first, and then use `profileId_postId`

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you for reply. Please give suggestion and code to get that user profileId too. I have only the url which is copied from the facebook App.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstput userId underscore add postId /Likes to check Like status in facebook**

**userId_post_Id/Likes to fetch Likes Records**

**userId_post_Id/Comments to fetch Comments Records**

```
    https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=303261006522998_751199848395776%2FLikes&version=v2.9

    **In this link Right side Get Token indide GetAccessToken to select Permission**
```

[image]

```
    303261006522998_751199848395776/Likes
    303261006522998_751199848395776/Comments

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "124778301449917",
      "name": "Manisha Gera"
    },
    {
      "id": "1680577265523548",
      "name": "Rubi Sharma"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTI0Nzc4MzAxNDQ5OTE3",
      "after": "MTY4MDU3NzI2NTUyMzU0OAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need permission  user_id or user_likes