# Posting likes to facebook post in the graph api returns an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app and I have `publish_actions` allowed for the users registered.
I have created a facebook post on some test wall: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=189793004799930&id=100013076942056

I took the object id: `189793004799930` and made a request with a user access token to post a like on his name according to this api reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes

I am getting the error:  `"invalid_request" "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`.

If I take the user id and the post id (100013076942056_189793004799930) as mentioned here: [How should we retrieve an individual post now that /[post-id] is deprecated in v2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v)

I get the error: `invalid_request" "(#100) Story does not exist or user does not have permission to interact with it` even though i have permissions

**Update**
this is the permissions I have for the user: This is the scope I ask `publish_actions,email`, is this suitable with user posts? or page posts?

Comment: What permissions do you have? Since this is a post on a user timeline, it might be that you need to get permission to “see” that post in the first place, meaning you’d need `user_ posts` permission from the post owner.

Comment: @CBroe this is the permissions I have for the user: This is the scope I ask publish_actions,email, is this suitable with user posts? or page posts?

Comment: If it is a user posts, your app most likely needs to be able to read that post in the first place, so you would need user_posts from the owner.

Comment: @CBroe , Thanks, Can I "like" a page post instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may only like page posts and not user posts with the given permissions.