# Facebook graph API post details from Post_Id

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the post details from a PostId.

I have noticed that the Faceboook graph API documentation,
[Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post)

Find the post details by using the below path,
Post /{post-id}

It gets an error,

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /{post-id}",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "AcvdFFnlb1S"
  }
}
```

[I am using the facebook graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: You need to use the “full form”, that combines the posting person/profiles id and the post id, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31354218/1427878

Comment: @CBroe : not worked, same issue again . "Unknown path components: /user_id}_{post_id}"

Comment: Please show the exact request you are making. And also, where did you get the post id from in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe : I am likely to get the post details by using the graph API , https://graph.facebook.com/Post/681727415232133_1580395018698697

Comment: What is `/Post/` doing in there? You want `https://graph.facebook.com/681727415232133_1580395018698697`

Comment: @CBroe : In facebook API documentation, there is an api like  Post/{post_id}

Comment: It does not say anywhere that this was an API request path ... that is just the headline of the page, that shows that this is about the `Post` object type, and that those are accessed via `/{post-id}`

Comment: @CBroe: Thank you. Then, By using this only get the story,Id and time.. How can I get the post whole details.

Comment: Since API v2.4, you need to ask for the fields you want.