# Error when trying to implement facebook social login

Tags: flutter, dart

I was working on some dart programs and I wanted to implement Facebook login in one of the codes. I tried implementing it, but I keep getting this error and was wondering if I could get any help.

This is the function that allows the Facebook login

``

```
Future<FirebaseUser> startFacebookLogin() async{
    var facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
    final result = await 
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email','public_profile']);
    FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
    switch(result.status){
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        AuthCredential credential= FacebookAuthProvider.
           getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.
           instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        return firebaseUser;
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("Facebook sign in cancelled by user");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("Facebook sign in failed");
        break;
}
```

``

and this part implements startFacebookLogin to the FloatingActionButton

``

```
Expanded(
   child: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
         child: new FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => startFacebookLogin().then((FirebaseUser 
               firebaseUser) => print(firebaseUser))
                  .catchError((e) => print(e)),
            child: new Icon(const IconData(0xe900, fontFamily: 'facebook')),
               backgroundColor: Colors.blue,),
   ),
),
```

``

One error message that I keep getting is this line

(#12) singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher

I figure that something is wrong or missing in the startFacebookLogin(), but can't find what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `await facebookSignIn.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);` instead of`facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email','public_profile']);` remove `public_profile`

You should only get that message if you are trying to access a post object using its own id only check this [respond](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31353591/1427878)!

Comment: ``facebookSignIn``doesn't exist anymore, so I can't really use that. Also, removing ``public_profile`` didn't really work out.