# Facebook Graph API Individual Posts fields

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v/31354218#31354218) to select an individual post from a user's feed.

I am using [PHP Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) on the latest version 5.7.

Previously this had worked with no problem, I made my request like:

```
$response = $this->fb->get(
  '/'.$user['id']. '_' .$post_id.'/?fields=id,description,name,full_picture',
   $this->get_access_token()
);
```

And I would get all the fields. However, over the last few months, this has stopped working.

The `access_token` requests the following permissions:

```
['user_events', 'user_posts']
```

I can't find any documentation on the solution outlined in the [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v/31354218#31354218). So I am not sure if I need any more permissions.

I do not get an error when sending this request, I just get the ID back and nothing else. This can be confirmed in the Graph API Explorer:

[image: Graph API Explorer]

The [v5.0 docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/post) show that when requesting a post I can get `full_picture`, `name` and `description` without mentioning any additional permissions required.

However that same page recommends making the request with just the post ID:

```
/* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{post-id}',
    '{access-token}'
  );
}
```

Which does not work, you

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "ACs2rpwobcW8zSFyL_0Q2yQ"
  }
}
```

The error does mention `statuses` and not `posts` but I am not sure how to distinguish the difference between those, I figured they were the same.

Has anyone else stumbled across this and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the fact it was called `status` was important. I made a request to the users feed, and noticed that some older posts were returning the data that I needed. I had a look through the list of fields and appended `message` and `type` to get the following response:

[image]

Not very well documented I guess. But got there in the end, hopefully this can help someone else in future.

Comment: It certainly helped me! Thanks.