# Retrieving Page Reviewer ID Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're building a tool to allow business owners to view and respond to all their messages/reviews in one place. I'm currently in charge of building the Facebook reviews section.

Currently I've worked out how to retrieve all the pages recommendations: `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{pageId}/ratings?fields=created_time%2crecommendation_type%2creview_text%2copen_graph_story&access_token={token}`

So far, that all works as expected, the problems begin to arise when trying to programmatically respond to the review. Based on my current research, I've found that previously to respond to a comment you'd POST to this endpoint:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{recommendationId}/comments?access_token={token}&message={message}`

But as of more recently, it appears that's changed to: `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{posterId}_{recommendationId}/comments?access_token={token}&message={message}`

Source: ([How should we retrieve an individual post now that /[post-id] is deprecated in v2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v)).

Considering that the ratings API no longer allows the `reviewer` field, how would I go about retrieving the ID of the review's poster?

Comment: Still needing an answer to this.