How to get all the comments of a user's public Facebook post?
I've tried gettinggraph.facebook.com/v20.0/1*************3_7*************1/comments, where
1*************3 is a valid user id, and7*************1 is a valid (and public) post id.
Unfortunately, the Graph API Explorer shows an OAuthException:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1*************3_7*************1' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "A*********************Z"
  }
}

How could I get all the comments of a user's public Facebook post?
I'd prefer a Graph API (or other official Meta tool) solution.
But I'm open to other approaches too.

Relevant, but not a duplicate (mine is not that specific, not limited to the Graph API):
Get comments of public facebook post

This one is similar too, but not a duplicate, because I don't necessarily need a Facebook app for this task. Get all comments on a public Facebook post

Researching the phrasing of the error message should have lead you to https://stackoverflow.com/q/31353591/1427878 quite quickly.

@C3roe I initially didn’t think that post applied, as I’m trying to retrieve a list of comments, not an individual post. I see now that I could have explored it further, so I appreciate your input. I’ll try modifying my query to graph.facebook.com/v20.0/userId_postId/comments and see where it leads.

@C3roe The userId_postId syntax leads to an other exception, unfortunately. I'm afraid that stackoverflow.com/q/31353591/1427878 doesn't have a solution for getting all the comments of a user's public Facebook post. But it was useful for taking a step ahead, thank you.

One possible solution
Ask the creator of the post to give permission to your Facebook app. Once your app has the user_posts permission from the post owner, your app will have access to the comments on the user's post too.
Quote from the Graph API reference

A page access token can read all posts posted to or posted by that
Page.
A page access token with the pages_manage_posts permission and
Page Public Content Access Feature are required to read publicly
shared Page posts. The person requesting the access token must be an
admin of the Page.
A user access token can read any post your application created on behalf of that user.
A user's post can be read if the owner has granted the user_posts permission.
A user access token may read a post that user is tagged in if they have
granted the user_posts permission. However, in some cases the
post's owner's privacy settings may not allow your application to
access it.

Source of the quote:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/
